# Debugging Linked Lists in c++ program to Add Two Numbers: Can someone explain why l3=l3->next; leads to the error?

Tags: c++, linked-list, runtime

**Context:**

Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4) Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8. Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807.

Get the following error:

> Line 40: member access within
>   null pointer of type >'struct ListNode'?

Don't understand what is wrong.. Can someone explain why >l3=l3->next; leads to the error?

```
/**
     * Definition for singly-linked list.
     * struct ListNode {
     *     int val;
     *     ListNode *next;
     *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
     * };
     */

    class Solution {
    public:
        ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
            ListNode* l3;
            ListNode dummy(INT_MIN);
            l3= &dummy;

            //l3->val=3;
            //l3=l3->next;
            int i=0;
            int n1=0;
            while(l1)
            {
                n1+=(l1->val)*(pow(10,i));
                l1=l1->next;
                i++;       
            }
            int j=0;
            int n2=0;
            while(l2)
            {
                n2+=(l2->val)*(pow(10,j));
                l2=l2->next;
                j++;            
            }
            int n3=n1+n2;
            while(n3)
            {
                l3->val=n3%10;
                n3=n3/10;
                cout<<l3->val<<endl;
                cout<<dummy.next<<endl;
                l3=l3->next;
            }   

            return dummy.next;

        }
    };
```

Comment: Please use a debugger *and draw the list*.  Edit the post with the results of your debugging session.

Comment: _Can someone explain why >l3=l3->next; leads to the error?_  Probably because `I3->next` is `nullptr` and you are attribuiting it to I3 and derreferencing it later

Comment: so how do you define the size of a linked list?

Answer (score 0):

I myself have the same issue...

#### Reason

What the error message

```
member access within null pointer of type >'struct ListNode'?
```

shows that your struct pointer tries to access a memory address **which is `NULL`** right now.

So it shows that it's a runtime error, which means that it happens at the runtime stage.

#### Solution

When you try to access the content where the pointer pointing at, make sure it's not `NULL`.

```
if( ListNodePtr != NULL){
    ListNodePtr = ListNodePtr->next;
}
```

or

```
ListNodePtr = ListNodePtr ?  ListNodePtr->next : NULL;
```

Hope you nail down this problem on LeetCode.